# Find Node that start with given String using Simple XML Element

Tags: php, simplexml

I have xml of following form

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
  <vehicle>
    <stockno>3C </stockno>
    <image1 />
    <image2 />
  </vehicle>
</root>
```

Now I want to find all the node that start with string 'image', what can I do ?

Below is the code I have tried

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open('vehicle_274.xml');
while ($xml->read()){
    if (
        $xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && 
        $xml->name == 'vehicle'
    ){
        $node = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXML());
        $result = $node->xpath("//image");
        print_r(count($result));
    }
}
```

This code require image tag instead of searching for one that start with 'image'

Answer (score 2):

It finds what you ask. To lookup tags which names start with `image` write so:

```
//*[starts-with(name(), "image")]
```